# Imagesc set the yscale

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I have a function say `Echo` of `size 100*100`. I use:

```
x=linspace(-5000, 5000, 100); y=linspace(-200, 200, 100);imagesc(x, y, Echo);
```

I see the image is not properly oriented, so if I use:

```
Echo=rot90(Echo); imagesc(x, y, Echo);
```

I get the desired image but the `yscale` is starting from 200 (lower right) to -200 (upper right). I want -200 (lower right) and 200 (upper right). How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

- [`flipud`](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/flipud.html) on the matrix
- or modify the figure/[axes](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/axis.html) properties: `axis ij` (compare with `axis xy`)

Comment: As I said before if I used Echo=rot90(Echo) then the image was fine but Y axis was opposite. With your idea if I do: Echo1=rot90(Echo) Echo=flipud(Echo1) then axis is fine because image is now 180 degree shifted and that I do not want. Image is changing his position only. No change in axis.

Answer (score 3):

In general if you want to reverse the direction of one of the axes *relative to the normal orientation used in figures* (example here: Y axis), use

```
set(gca,'YDir','reverse')
```

**Edit**

Since `imagesc` shows y axis in reverse orientation by default, try the following:

```
set(gca,'YDir','normal')
```

Note that in fact this is equivalent to @Bonlenfum's alternative suggestion of `axis xy`

Comment: It's not doing anything!

Comment: Yes. Problem is solved but with set(gca,'YDir','normal') I have also to use rot90(Echo, -1) [not rot90(Echo, 1)]. and it's also working simply by axis xy;

Comment: Great! If one of the answers worked best please click on the checkmark next to it...